# Type Error url is not JSON serializable in Scrapy with Selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using python scrapy with selenium here i added the code

```
import scrapy
from examble.items import exambleItem
from selenium import webdriver


class exambleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "examble"
    allowed_domain = ['examble.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.examble.com/kids/page-1.html']

    def parse(self,response):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get(response)
        for i in range(1,36):
            item = ExambleItem()
            item['Name'] = 'sdds'       
            #driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            #driver.get(response)
            xpath = "//*[@id='wrapper']/main/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[%d]/td[1]/a" % i
            elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
            elem.click()
            yield item
```

in this i run the code with scrapy crawl Type error occurs the error is TypeError <200 http://www.examble.com/kids/page-1.html> is not JSON Serializable

I am replacing driver.get(response) with driver.get('http://www.examble.com/kids/page-1.html') it runs what should be the exact error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response` is a `scrapy.Response` object. What you are looking here is `response.url` since `driver.get()` requires a string argument.

Just replace `response` to `response.url` in:

```
driver.get(response)
```